# How do I make a composer template that will display what is currently on the canvas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I load a saved template in the composer it always displays the canvas content it was saved with.  This seems counter intuitive to me.

Is there a way to save a template with an empty map item that gets filled with the contents of the current canvas so I don't have to delete the map and re-add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use "set to map canvas extent" option in the map properties, that way you don't have to re-add a map object